# Does the fact that a linear transformation $L$ from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$ preserves length imply that $A^TA=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question states:
"Consider a linear transoformation $L$ from $\Bbb R^m$ to $R^n$ that preserves length. Let $A$ be the matrix of $L$... What is $A^TA$? What about $AA^T$?"

Here is what I have found out so far:
We first notice that $A$ need not be an orthogonal matrix since $m$ need not equal to $n$. Since $L$ preserves legnth and the only vector that has length $0$ is the zero vector, $ker(L) = \{ 0 \}$. This means that $A$ has a leading 1 in every column, which implies that $dim(im(L)) = rank(A) =$ number of columns of $A = m$. That $A$ has a leading 1 in every column also implies that $n \ge m$. That $A$ has a leading 1 in every column implies that columns of $A$ are linearly independent. Also, $\{ 0 \} = ker(A) = ker(A^TA)$, so $A^TA$ is invertible. Also, if $m$ is strictly less than $n$, then the rref of $A^T$ has at least one column free, meaning that $A^Tx = 0$ has infinitely many solutions, meaning that $AA^Tx=0$ has infinitely many solutions and hence not invertible.

This is what I have found out so far. I was wondering whether $A^TA$ has to be the identity matrix. I've tried to figure out an counterexample, but failed.

Comment: While $A$ doesn't need to be square, it must have orthonormal columns.

Comment: Thanks so much. And why is that?

Comment: Because the standard unit vectors of $\Bbb R^m$ have to be sent to unit length, pairwise orthogonal vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have for any two vectors $v,w\in\mathrm R^m$:
\begin{align}
v\cdot w &= (A v)\cdot (A w) && \text{by assumption}\\
&= (A v)^T (A w) && \text{definition of dot product}\\
&= v^T A^T A w && \text{property of the transpose}
\end{align}
Now consider the standard basis.